# Is it possible to setup a wireless network without internet for the robot and PC?

Tags: ros, wifi

The system includes three devices: PC, robot's computer, and wireless device.

In order to improve the signal quality of the wireless in the whole robot's environment. I'd like to put a big wireless device in the middle corridor where it is not Ethernet (no internet) and only feed by power, then use its signal to connects it with the robot's computer. The robot's computer has a small wireless device that will connect with a big wireless device. Both wireless devices have no internet, only electric power, and signal.

Can I transmit data from the robot to my PC and vice versa over Wi-Fi's signal ?

Can I access the robot's computer using Wi-Fi's signal to launch the robot ?

If yes, please your suggestions, and what are its disadvantages?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: the system is working fine now using the internet in the big wireless device and connect it with the robot's computer and PC, only some problem when the robot is very far from a big wireless device because of dropping the signal quality to 5% [here](https://dot11ap.wordpress.com/cwna/radio-frequency-rf-technologies/rssi/)

Comment: What do you mean by "big wireless device"? Are you referring to the network router? It sounds like you need to add a wireless bridge to extend your range. What data rate do you require and at what range?

Comment: Yes, it is a router. But I'd like to connect them without internet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set up a new router that is not connected to the internet. This gives you an isolated network that only local devices can see and connect with. You can even hide the SSID so it can be even more private. This requires the expense of purchasing a new router but has the advantage that you can use a router with multiple high gain antennas and your range for the robot is limited by the range to the fixed router, not to the computer which may be on the other end of the routers range. This effectively gives you twice the range to the computer from the robot with the right setup. If the robot always operates in the same area, this is most ideal.

Another option is to use the WIFI controller on the robot as an access point (most WIFI controllers can do this) and connect your computer to that SSID each time you want to communicate with the robot. This SSID may also be hidden if you like that option. The down side of this is that you'll have to use a high gain antenna (not likely supplied) on the robot in order to get a decent range to the computer. This will not have the same range as with the router, even using high gain antennas. The plus side is that you can follow the robot with the computer and you essentially have an unlimited area of operation as long as you can be close to the robot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Your answer is my main plan. My question is a temporal solution for my existing hardware.

Comment: The issue is ridiculous, I didn't understand the task of some lines perfectly. export ROS_HOSTNAME=ip for master
export ROS_IP=ip for master
export  ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ip for slave:11311

Comment: To remove internet connectivity, remove the wire from your router that is plugged in to the WAN port. All local devices will remain connected to the local network, but there will be no internet access.

Comment: You have a right, that is I did.

Comment: Those ROS environmental variables don't require internet access unless you set the ip to something that is not on your local net AND you call those environmental variables in such a way as you wait until you establish a connection until you do anything else. This doesn't seem like a likely scenario.

Comment: On our robot some years ago, we took some cheap wi-fi router, removed the plastic case, zip-tied it to some free space and hard-wired it to the robot's battery :)